# Laravel: how to insert data with foreign key

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys

I'm having trouble with the foreign key.
I have two tables. users table and user_address table. I'll show you the migration.

users table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and this is the user_address table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_address', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->integer('mobile_no')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('street')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('state')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I don't know what to add or to insert in controllers / models / web routes. :( please help me out.

I have Models for users and user_address
users model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role_name',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function setUsernameAttribute($value) {
        if ( empty($value) ) {
        $this->attributes['username'] = NULL;
        } else {
            $this->attributes['username'] = $value;
        }
    }
```

and the user_address table:

```
class User_Address extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'mobile_no',
        'shipping_address',
        'barangay',
        'city',
        'province',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Show your code; do you have a model for User? Do you have a model for Address? Is `user_address` a pivot table (i.e. can multiple Users have the same Address?) We're gonna need more information in order to help you.

Comment: I have Models for users and user_address. but only the protected fillable

Comment: Perfect; much better. So now you should probably setup a relationship between `User` and `UserAddress` (note: there shouldn't be a `_` in Class Names). This this case, a `User` can have many `UserAddress` records: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. Then you'll need to add logic to create or update UserAddress (`$user->addresses()->create(...);` or `$user->addresses()->where(...)->first()->update(...));`, etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like that:

```
$user_post=request()->get('name','username','email');
$address_post=request()->get('street','city','address')

$user = new User();
$user -> fill($user_post];
$user->save();


$id=$user->id;

$address_post['user_id']=$id;
$address = new UserAdress();
$address -> fill($user_address);
$address -> save();
```

I don't remember now if it should be fill() or insert().

Comment: where should i put this? store, create or update?

Comment: I was thinking about controller, that's why this code gets data from request(). User send post request (by form), and in route.php you declare that this request fires controller, that put this data to database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a relationship in the User model to start with

```
public function address() {
    return $this->hasOne(Addres::class, 'user_id);
}
```

you can probably get away by doing

```
tap(
   User::create(request()->get('name','username','email')), 
   fn($user)=> $user->address()
             ->save(request()->get('street','city','address')
)
```

Or without relationship, you will have to do something like

```
tap(
   User::create(request()->get('name','username','email')), 
   fn($user)=> Address::create[array_merge(
             ['user_id' => $user->id], 
             request()->get('street','city','address')
           )
```